# Grouping by datetime by hour in dataframe

Tags: python, group-by

I try to use this:

```
casa_consumo_h = casa_consumo['date'].groupby(lambda x: x.hour).mean()
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

My date is of this type:

```
date             55535 non-null datetime64[ns]
```

How can I group by hour my dataframe?

```
date                         Ac      f      I      Pf     R       V
0   2017-08-01 00:00:00     37      59.97   1.49    0.4     10  22
1   2017-08-01 00:00:01     302     59.97   1.51    0.8     10  22
2   2017-08-01 00:00:03     3077    59.97   1.49    0.8     10  22
3   2017-08-01 00:00:05     300     59.97   1.50    0.8     15  22
```

Comment: Can you post a slightly larger sample of your dataframe so we can reproduce this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby(df['date'].dt.hour).mean()
```

Output:

```
          Ac      f       I   Pf      R     V
date                                         
0     301.78  59.97  1.4975  0.7  11.25  22.0
```